# Yocto Useradd Fails

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I cannot add a user in Yocto and I am unsure why. My recipe is `useradd.bb` and it contains

```
DESCRIPTION = "Add a new user 'nfi' with sudo privileges and change root password"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

# Inherit necessary classes
inherit useradd
inherit extrausers

# Ensure the 'sudo' group exists and set the root password
# Replace 'hashed_root_password' with the actual hashed password
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "\
    groupadd -f sudo; \
    usermod -p toor root; \
"

# Configure the new user 'nfi'
USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
USERADD_PARAM_${PN} = "--user nfi --password nfi --create-home --groups sudo"

do_install() {
    echo 'nfi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/sudoers.d/nfi
}

FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/sudoers.d"
```

This should be very simple but I constantly see the log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot the lines

```
Running useradd commands...
NOTE: useradd: Performing useradd with [--root /mnt/YoctoDrive/Documents/master/EVCC_Application/build-fb/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/useradd/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot --user nfi --password nfi --create-home]
useradd: listing attributes of /etc/skel/.bashrc: No data available
ERROR: useradd: useradd command did not succeed.
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated:
```

This is then followed by a large chunk of python code. Can anyone potentially explain the issue here?

Edit: I am using Hardknott. I have tried using two computers and multiple workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `extrausers` class to create a new user in the System, and `useradd` to a user with a specific recipe.

I would try:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Add a new user 'nfi' with sudo privileges and change root password"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

EXCLUDE_FROM_WORLD = "1"
INHIBIT_DEFAULT_DEPS = "1"

ALLOW_EMPTY:${PN} = "1"

inherit useradd

USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"

GROUPADD_PARAM:${PN} = "nfi"

USERADD_PARAM:${PN} = "-G adm,sudo,users,plugdev,audio,video,dialout,input -m -d /home/nfi -p <PASSWORD_HERE> nfi"
```